# which directory to install solr for magento

Tags: solr, magento-1.4

i want to install solr on my server for magento. is there a specific directory i should install it in?

my java -version

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.9) (rhel-1.36.1.11.9.el5_9-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

i went to 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-use-the-solr-search-engine-with-magento-enterprise-edition

and it says i should enter the following code

```
cd empty-directory
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/3.5.0/apache-solr-3.5.0.tgz
```

but i don't know which directory it will install it in

later it says "For example, if Solr is installed in /etc/solr/apache-solr-3.5.0 and Magento is installed in /var/www/magento, enter:"

so i should create a directory "solr" under "/etc"?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where you install Solr. But the /opt or /var/opt directory are probably better places to install then /etc.